# Wannabe Array to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to take an object that looks like this : `[ '1,23' , '4,56' , '7,89' ]` to an Array. Although it looks like one, it isnt. It is an typeof acuses it as a object.

I tried toArray, forEach, splice with comma (cant due to the middle numbers).

Anyway, can anyone give me a hand. I'm trying really hard with something that , at least, looks easy.

Comment: What makes you say that that isn't an array?

Comment: it is an object if i inspect it. it does not loop through it... and the "typeof" is object type.

Comment: sounds like you need  [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), `if (typeof yourArray ==='object')` then do something like `Object.entries(yourArray)`

Comment: Can you show us how it was created?

Comment: Do you want your output to look like this: `['1', '23', '4', '56', '7', '89']`, or like this `[['1', '23'], ['4', '56'], ['7', '89']]`, or as-is? Because if you want it as-is, you might just get away with `yourArray = JSON.parse(yourObject.toString())`

Comment: It was created in a form with a table composed with inputs with same name. Something like a table of name="apple[grape]"

Comment: I want an output like [1.23, 4.56, 7.89]...an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the array of strings to an array of numbers, you can use map and parseFloat to get the strings to numbers as well as replace to swap the "," for a "." for each string..

```js
var arr = [ '1,23' , '4,56' , '7,89' ];
var newArr = arr.map(item => parseFloat(item.replace(/,/,'.')))


console.log(newArr); // gives [1.23, 4.56, 7.89]
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript's `typeof` does not have a separate value for array, it returns "object". You can check if a value is an array with the `Array.isArray` function.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
typeof a == "object"
Array.isArray(a) == true
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, by replacing each element's , with . and then parsing.

```js
const input = ['1,23', '4,56', '7,89']

const outputString = input.map(it => it.replace(',', '.'))

const outputFloat = input.map(it => it.replace(',', '.')).map(it => parseFloat(it))

console.log(outputString)
console.log(outputFloat)
```